# Trouble running my code through the shell command

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment for class and I got my code to run correctly, but when i run it through the shell it doesnt return correctly.

In shell my arugments are "apple" "banana" "cherry"
and it should return apple and banana

it returns an empty list []. if i run `sys.argv[1]` it returns `apple`. I know I'm close, but figure out this last part.

```py
import sys
set_a = sys.argv[1:]
set_b = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange']

common_list=[]

def common(*args):
    for word in args:
        for word2 in set_b:
            if word == word2:
                common_list.append(word2)
    print({str(common_list)})
    #print("{"+str(s)[1:-1]+"}")

common(set_a)
```

Comment: `word2` is a string and `word` is a list of strings. So `if word == word2` never is true.

Comment: The shell tag is for questions about POSIX-family shell languages (unless you tag for another shell language; Python isn't one). Removed some other irrelevant tags as well ("CPU word" is for questions that relate to CPU register size; "list" is typically too generic to be helpful as a tag -- the places it's most appropriate are data structure implementation questions)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the asterisk in the `args` parameter for `common` function I think. Remove it seems to work for me

```
import sys
set_a = sys.argv[1:]
set_b = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange']

common_list=[]

def common(args):
    for word in args:
        for word2 in set_b:
            if word == word2:
                common_list.append(word2)
    print({str(common_list)})

common(set_a)
```

Also I think you can shorten the code somewhat by check if `word` is in `set_b` by using `in` operator (`word in set_b`) instead of manually iterating through `set_b` in a `for` loop

```
import sys
set_a = sys.argv[1:]
set_b = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange']

common_list=[]

def common(args):
    for word in args:
        if word in set_b:
            common_list.append(word)
    print({str(common_list)})

common(set_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem:

```
def common(*args):
    for word in args:
```

The purpose of `*args` is to allow a function to accept a variable number of arguments.

`for word in args` loops through each *argument*.  Since you only passed one argument, this loop runs exactly once.

In the loop, `word` is the list `sys.argv[1:]`, because that is the argument that was passed.  The loop does **not** iterate over the *contents* of the argument, as you seem to expect.

If I change your code to `def common(args):`, it works as expected.

Comment: thank you, in my mind i was entering multiple arguemnts through the sys,argv, but obviously when i called the function i only had the one argument in there. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answers, the problem is in `args` and `*args`.

Also you can convert the list of known ingredients a set to speed up search (and remove the double for-loops):

```py
import sys

my_set = {"apple", "banana", "mango", "orange"}  # <-- use set instead of a list


def common(args):
    return [word for word in args if word in my_set]


c = common(sys.argv[1:])
print(*c, sep=" ")
```

Prints (from my shell):

```py
andrej@MyPC:~/app$ python3 script.py apple banana cherry
apple banana
```

Answer (score 0):

`print([f for f in sys.argv[1:] if f in set_b])`

p.s. if lists are sets as it named, then
`print(set(sys.argv[1:]) & set(set_b))`